# trying to output the correct value from SQL query from comparing a different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm very new with SQL and need assistance on how I can accomplish this task using the correct query.

I have 2 tables that I need to use. Table "TB1" has:

```
id Name
1  bob
2  blow
3  joe
```

table "TB2" has:

```
compid property
1      bob
2      blow
```

I am trying to get which compid is missing in "TB2" and insert it from "TB1"

the query I am doing is:

```
SELECT id, name from TB1, TB2 where id <> compid
```

what I get is 2 ouputs of Id 1, and 2, and 3 outputs from id 3. by using php:

```
for($i=0;$i <= mysql_num_rows($comp)-1; $i++)
{
 echo mysql_result($comp, $i, 0)."<br>";


}
```

and I expected the ouput 3 but instead got this:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
```

I understand its comparing all the rows within the table but is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing an implicit Cartesian `JOIN` which results in every row against every other row. You need to specify what attribute `JOIN`s the two tables.

Using implicit syntax (not recommended):

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM TB1, TB2 
WHERE id <> compid
  AND TB1.Name = TB2.property <-- Column join
```

Using explicit syntax:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM TB1
JOIN TB2
  ON TB2.property = TB1.Name <-- Column join
WHERE id <> compid
```

To accomplish your goal you would need something along the lines of:

```
SELECT TB1.id, TB1.name
FROM TB1
LEFT JOIN TB2
  ON TB2.property = TB1.Name
WHERE TB2.compid IS NULL
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dac4e/1)

It's best practice to always alias the columns you select to prevent ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

To select it you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TB1 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT compid 
    FROM TB2
);
```