# Mysql select all rows except ones which are in another table

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need SQL Query to find Parent records without child records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839500/need-sql-query-to-find-parent-records-without-child-records)

I have a table one and two,

```
select name from one
```

let say i have 3 rows a, b, c

```
select name from table two;
```

and let say I have 3 rows in table two which are contains a, d , f

I want to `select * from table one` where name are not in table two so i should end up with
b,c and not a because a is in the table two

Please advice thanks

Comment: Refer this link :


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689378/trying-to-output-the-correct-value-from-sql-query-from-comparing-a-different-tab/13689645#13689645

Comment: PLease write your sql statement clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `NOT EXISTS` clause

```
SELECT name from one
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM two
    WHERE two.name = one.name
)
```

### Update

Alternatively, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` with a `NULL` qualifier

```
SELECT one.name FROM one
LEFT JOIN two on one.name = two.name
WHERE two.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a subquery to get the names from table two and use them to exlude rows from table one

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM table2)